# Which mail server do you prefer on linux

Tags: postfix, exim, email

What mail server software do you prefer and why on e.g. Debian 5 (Lenny)?

- Exim
- Postfix
- Qmail
- Other

Comment: This is a subjective question and should be a community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of these MTAs have similar features. All of them can handle large amounts of mail; can interact with databases in many formats.
But, I prefer Postfix and i use it in all my servers, it's easy to administrate, secure and robust.

Answer (score 1):

I use postfix and sendmail only diff is postfix is easy to config and manage sendmail is go bit slow

Answer (score 1):

Can I plug [citadel](http://www.citadel.org/) instead? Simply for the easy setup and the many features that it has. It is more than just an email server - boasts group-ware and advanced communications functions with a web-based interface. It may be worth considering if you are intending to grow your service beyond just a plain MTA.

From the website: email, calendaring/scheduling, address books, bulletin boards, mailing list server, instant messaging, multiple domain support, modern AJAX-style web interface.